# i am doing material designing in android i have a error at setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, material-design

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); //not working
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

the error occurred is setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)  in AppCompactActivity cannot be applied to android.widget.toolbar,my toolbar.xml is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error:**

> setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) in
>   AppCompactActivity cannot be applied to android.widget.toolbar,my
>   toolbar.xml

You are getting this error becuase you have used `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in `XML` while you are importing `android.widget.toolbar` in your `Activity`.

Try

```
setActionBar(mToolbar);
```

instead of

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

or

import `Toolbar` from `android.support.v7.widget` package.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score 1):

you must import

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

not

```
android.widget.toolbar
```